JerseyTest and Mockito - problem with mocking an object
My aim is to learn a little bit about mocking objects in the context of Jersey Test.
I have 3 classes:
ServiceController
package com.vogella.jersey.first;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class ServiceController {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ServiceController.class);

    public String returnSth(String inSth) {
        return "returned RET" + inSth;
    }

}

Hello
package com.vogella.jersey.first;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @Inject
    private ServiceController serviceController;

    private String inStr = "BLA";

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey" + serviceController.returnSth(inStr);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
                + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + serviceController.returnSth(inStr) + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
    }

} 

HelloTest
package com.vogella.jersey.first;

import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

class HelloTest extends JerseyTest {

    private ServiceController serviceController;

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(Hello.class);
        serviceController = mock(ServiceController.class);
        config.register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(ServiceController.class).to(ServiceController.class);
            }
        }
        );
        return config;
    }

    @Test
    public void helloResponseCodeOK() {
        Response response = target("hello").request()
                .get();

        assertEquals("Http Response should be 200: ", Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());

    }

    @Test
    public void helloResponseTextIsCorrect() {
        when(serviceController.returnSth(any(String.class))).thenReturn("RetFromMock");

        Response response = target("hello").request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .get();

        assertTrue("Hello Jerseyreturned RETBLA".equals(response.readEntity(String.class)));

    }

}

So in the Hello class there is a "hello" endpoint and in 2 methods there is a call to a "returnSth" method from the injected ServiceController.
In HelloTest I wanted to test the "hello" endpoint but without calling the real serviceController.returnSth method - instead wanted to mock it and return some other string - "RetFromMock" regardless of the input.
However during the test execution the mocking is ineffective and still the real one is getting called. I would expect the assertTrue to fail, because if the mock would get called, the response output should be "Hello JerseyRetFromMock" but is always "Hello Jerseyreturned RETBLA".
I was trying different ways of instantiating the mock:
Injecting:
@Inject
private ServiceController serviceController;

Mocking with annotations:
@Mock
private ServiceController serviceController;

@InjectMocks
private ServiceController serviceController;

Those attempts were resulting in NullPointerException (serviceController was null).
The above I tried also with @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) annotation with the same result.
I also tried to follow the example from this link:
https://medium.com/@mnu/overriding-dependency-injection-with-hk2-in-jersey-tests-4756144c2399
but was never able to get the "bind(serviceController).to(ServiceController.class)" to work - failing with IllegalArgumentException.
============================
EDIT after few iterations with @knittl in the comments
currently the HelloTest looks like this:
package com.vogella.jersey.first;

import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

class HelloTest extends JerseyTest {

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceController serviceController;

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(Hello.class);
        //serviceController = mock(ServiceController.class);
        config.register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(ServiceController.class).to(ServiceController.class);
            }
        }
        );
        return config;
    }

    @Test
    public void helloResponseCodeOK() {
        Response response = target("hello").request()
                .get();

        assertEquals("Http Response should be 200: ", Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());

    }

    @Test
    public void helloResponseTextIsCorrect() {
        //configure();

        when(serviceController.returnSth(any(String.class))).thenReturn("RetFromMock");

        Response response = target("hello").request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .get();

        assertTrue("Hello Jerseyreturned RETBLA".equals(response.readEntity(String.class)));

    }

}

and getting "HelloTest.helloResponseTextIsCorrect:64 InvalidUseOfMatchers" pointing to the line with the "when thenReturn" line.

You must extend your with the @MockitoAnnotation if you want your annotations to actually have an effect. Otherwise they are completely ignored.

Hi thanks for your suggestion. I used MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this); and annotated serviceController with @InjectMocks and now getting another exception: HelloTest.helloResponseTextIsCorrect:62 InvalidUseOfMatchers. This pointing to this line: when(serviceController.returnSth(any(String.class))).thenReturn("RetFromMock"); Am I really misusing the "when thenReturn" syntax? At the moment I don't see how.

is serviceController a Mockito mock/spy instance? Note that there's already a anyString() matcher. I don't know when and how often configure is going to be called.

@knittl my intention is that it is a mock. In the core class "Hello" it is a dependency and inside the HelloTest I wanted to mock its reponse instead of calling the real one.

Did you check the value of serviceController when the exception is thrown? Is it the same instance assigned during your configure call? Is the configure method invoked before your tests run?

If I comment out the "when thenReturn" (in order to avoid the exception) then the return value from the serviceController.returnSth is "returned RETBLA" - so no surprise, the real method gets called. If it is not commented out then - no return value, because the exception prevents it. Re: the "configure" - as I introduced the "@MockitoAnnotation" and annotated the serviceController with "@InjectMocks" I no longer needed to initialize it in "configure". I don't call "configure" inside the test. I did such experiment, but it seems to have no effect whatsoever.

@knittl I edited the main post with the current status of the HelloTest class, so it is clear, what are we talking about.

I'm pretty sure the order of execution of init and configure is wrong. @InjectMocks can only inject mock fields that have been assigned. My guess is that configure is executed after init. That said, @InjectMocks does not create a mock but a real instance, and you can call when only with mock/spy objects. It's unclear which classes are under test and which classes should be mocked.

I don't know Jersey enough, but what exactly does the line bind(ServiceController.class).to(ServiceController.class); do? Where does your (non-)mock come into play? How will Jersey know about your HelloTest#serviceController field?

@knittl The Hello class is under test - I want to test the "hello" endpoint defined in it. The ServiceController is a dependency of Hello and should be mocked. I'll play with init and configure.

For the experiment I removed the "@BeforeEach" from init() and in the test method helloResponseTextIsCorrect I called "configure() and later init() with still the same effect (InvalidUseOfMatchers). I don't know Jersey well enough neither :) Thanks to this: "ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(Hello.class);" Jersey knows that when I execute "target("hello")" I want to call the "hello" endpoint from the class being tested (Hello).

Your question: "How will Jersey know about your HelloTest#serviceController field?" is probably the main question I'm struggling with. So yeah - I don't understand it perfectly and hence this thread exists.

Your linked Medium post (questions should be self-contained and not rely on external resources) has bind(postalService).to(PostalService.class) which is different from bind(PostalService.class).to(PostalService.class); with a comment "force overriding of the binding" – have you tried to do it like in the linked post?
